# How to find if a list is a subset of another list?

Tags: c++, list, subset

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* next;
};

bool propSubset(Node* p, Node* q) {
    if(q == nullptr) return false;
    if(p == nullptr && q != nullptr) return true;
    if(p->value < q->value) return false;
    if(p->value > q->value) return propSubset(p, q->next);
    return propSubset(p->next, q->next);
}
```

p is a subset of q if

- all elements of p are elements of q
- q has at least one element that is not in p.

p and q are both sorted in ascending order.

This is all I got but it doesn't work for case like p = {2, 4}, q = {1, 2, 3, 4}
How can I improve this? Thanks

Comment: Seems an odd definition, but it's just an extra size check on top of the normal `std::includes` then if you support the algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterative solution may be better. Given lists of arbitrary length you don't want to run the risk of running out of stack space.

Also the size factor comes into play since the non-intersecting elements in q can be randomly distributed.

You may want to restructure your code something like:

```
bool propSubset(Node* p, Node* q) {
  int len_q = length(q); // assuming you have length function.
  if (length(p) >= len_q) return false;

  for(int i=0; i < len_q && p != nullptr; ++i) {
    if (p->value == q->value) p = p->next;
    if (p->value < q->value) return false; // That particular value in p is not in q.
    q = q->next;
  }
  if (p == nullptr) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: the length function works for my recursive version, but it is good too.

Comment: Would prefer iterative way to avoid long recursion depths.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that q's element that is not in p is always at the very end of the list. You need to take into account that the extra element can be anywhere in the list and not just the end of the list and you'll be on the right path.